# What is the appropriate link fucntion in GEE for longitudinal data where distribution changes in time?

Tags: distributions, panel-data, generalized-estimating-equations

I'm modeling treatment outcome data in a GEE with Group, Time, and their interaction. At baseline everyone is highly symptomatic, thus the distribution is negatively skewed. At follow up most people got better, so the distribution is now positively skewed. Would negative binomial with log link be appropriate for this scenario?